# AngularJS : Service data binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to call a service in angular.js through a controller on load and return a promise.  I then expect the promise to be fulfilled and for the DOM to be updated.  This is not what happens.  To be clear, I am not getting an error.  The code is as follows.

```
app.controller('TutorialController', function ($scope, tutorialService) {
    init();
    function init() {
        $scope.tutorials = tutorialService.getTutorials();
    }
});
```

---

```
<div data-ng-repeat="tutorial in tutorials | orderBy:'title'">
    <div>{{tutorial.tutorialId}}+' - '+{{tutorial.title + ' - ' + tutorial.description}}</div>
</div>
```

---

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/tutorial-service/tutorials";

app.service('tutorialService', function ($http, $q) {   
    this.getTutorials = function () {
        var list;
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url:url,
            method:'GET'        
        })
        .then(function(data){
            list = data.data;
            deffered.resolve(list);
            console.log(list[0]);
            console.log(list[1]);
            console.log(list[2]);

        });
        return deffered.promise;
    };
});
```

Inside of the ".then()" function in the service, I log the results and I am getting what I expected there, it just never updates the DOM. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTutorials` returns promise by itself. So you have to do `then()` again.

```
tutorialService.getTutorials().then(function(data){
    $scope.tutorials = data;
});
```

Before that, [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) returns a promise with `success()` and `error()`.

Although you can also use `then` as well

> Since the returned value of calling the $http function is a promise,
>   you can also use the then method to register callbacks, and these
>   callbacks will receive a single argument – an object representing the
>   response.

So you are correct with that.

Answer (score 0):

What is your data coming from the http call look like?  Your code works - I created a version of it here http://jsfiddle.net/Cq5sm/ using `$timeout`.

So if your list looks like:

```
[{ tutorialId: '1',
   title : 'the title',
   description: 'the description'
 }]
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

In newer Angular versions (I think v 1.2 RC3+) you have to configure angular to get the unwrap feature working ([**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OOONryvybXjli5tg7LV0?p=preview)):

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []).config(function ($parseProvider) {
    $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true);
});
```

This allows you to directly assign the promise to the ng-repeat collection.

```
$scope.tutorials = tutorialService.getTutorials();
```

Beside that I personally prefer to do the wrapping manually:

```
tutorialService.getTutorials().then(function(tutorials){
    $scope.tutorials = tutorials;
});
```

I don't know the exact reason why they removed that feature from the default config but it looks like the angular developers prefer the second option too.

Comment: I guess because it becomes transparent that usage of `then` indicates a promise was returned from underlying call. I prefer it as well. :)

Comment: That may indeed be the reason, it's also one of the reasons why I prefer wrapping it myself. Another one of course is that I've configured restangular to always give me the complete repsonse including headers.